# Ubuntu 22.04 hangs after logon in gnome

Tags: gnome, 22.04

**Can anyone share a tip on how to get this system running correct again? Where to start?**

( I do mean: re-installing is something you do on a Windows computer, not on a Linux system  )

I have ubuntu 22.04 installed as a Hyper-V guest under Windows 11. Today I wanted to do something under Linux, and started this machine.

Almost always, I start doing upgrades (because the Linux machine might have been down for a month or more...), so I do: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`

Today, after running the updates, I did get a message that a reboot was needed, and after that, and after logon, gnome started to hang. mouse stopped working too...

CTRL+ALT+F3 still works, and I can logon there.

I looked at the logs (/var/log/syslog), and cannot find anything special.

P.S.: I have 4 Gb RAM, 4 CPUs, enough diskspace, network is working too, even when gnome is hanging.

EDIT: I created an animated gif showing the problem

- It starts on gnome desktop where a script: `while true; do date; sleep 1; done` is running
- I change screen using CTRL+ALT+F3 (where `top` is running)
- I change back to screen 1 (CTRL+ALT+F1)
- Need to logon again....
- The screen keeps running for about 11 seconds.

see:

[image: animated gif wit abov description]

Comment: Can anyone comment about which info is missing from this question ?

Comment: I installed another copy (same OS), same problem, so suggestions are welcome ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is a new kernel, it is updated.

```
$ cat /proc/version_signature
Ubuntu 5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1-generic 5.19.17
```

I must stop using Ubuntu, when my hardware cannot handle these automatic kernel updates...

I found out by installing Linux Mint, and after an upgrade of the kernel to 5.19 the same problems appeared. But luckily it's pretty easy to install an older kernel when using Mint. (an external link, showing to to do that is: [How To Roll Back A Kernel In Linux Mint](https://www.linux.org/threads/how-to-roll-back-a-kernel-in-linux-mint-21-1.43961/))